# Automatic Python version compatability checker?

Tags: python, compatibility

I am developing a Python package. It occurred to me that as my codebase changes that it would be useful to be able to automatically check what versions of Python are compatible. In general I could see this being a hard problem, but it seems to me like a naive approach that only looks at core syntax (f-formatting of strings, type hints, etc) to give an estimate of the earliest compatible version would still be useful.

Is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: Probably take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html

Comment: Are you changing from python 2 to 3? Please provide enough information about your question.

Answer (score -1):

1. write tests that use your code from the package
2. Decide what versions of python you to support
3. set up continuous integration (CI) that runs your tests on the the those versions of python you support.